# Trying to add a div to an append statement via a + and getting OBJECT OBJECT (jquery)

Tags: jquery

```
$('#columnList').append("<li>" + $(colInProcID) + "</li>");
```

Obviously, Im doing something wrong...not sure how to say the above so that I dont get [object object] in my list.

**Sorry, let me clarify ... the $(colInProcID) is a DIV that I want inserted into the list.  (sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's:

```
$( colInProcID ).wrap('li').appendTo('#columnList');
```

What is colInProcID?

Comment: Ahhh.. that kind of works but for some reason I do not see the LI now for that div in the list even though it is in there... weird

Comment: @toddv Are you using Firefox with the Firebug addin? You really should be if you're not so you can diagnose exactly what's happening in realtime. Consider it the jQuery IDE ;) [no, not really, but it sounds nice ~ but definitely install those two items if you haven't!!!!]

Comment: Yes, I am ...that is what I meant by not being able to see the LI from the WRAP in firebug.  Not sure why, but after doing the above, I just have DIV inside the list but its not wrapped in an LI

Answer (score 1):

```
$(colInProcID)
```

is a jQuery object, not a string. You'll need to specify which of the potentially many matches you want.

EDIT:

Remember that in the browser, while it's true that everything is textual (obviously negating images), what we work with in javascript are objects, such as a div object holding a text span or a paragraph or whatever. So when you grab it with jQuery via a selector, it's now a jQuery object wrapping another object (even if that target object is a string).

So, you have to either remove the reference to the jQuery object (by calling a array reference or what have you) or you have to use direct XHTML/XML/HTML inside your call.

```
$('#columnList').append("<li>" + $(colInProcID) + "</li>");
```

into

```
var stringToInsert = "<div><p>sometext</p></div>";
$('#columnList').append("<li>" + stringToInsert + "</li>");
```

or perhaps

```
var stringToInsert = $(colInProcID)[0];
$('#columnList').append("<li>" + stringToInsert + "</li>");
```

or someone suggested `.get(0)` which I think works too.

You have to remember the part about anything grabbed with a selector `$(colInProcID)` or `$("#SomeDivToUse")` is a jQuery object, not an XML object or a string.

Hope this clarified things just a tad, and helped you out.

Comment: Im sorry, that is a DIV that I want inserted...so I want to insert the entire DIV

Comment: thanks a ton for the info!  If I cant get the wrap thing to work, I may just have to build a new string div with a new id I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to get the DIV into the list

```
$('#columnList').append("<li id='appendedLI'>");
$(colInProcID).appendTo('#appendedLI');
```

I tried the .wrap function and thought it was going to work but for some reason, the LI never showed up in FF3 or IE7.